# Replace literal user and password from persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple maven project which conects to a postgrewql batabase, and in persistence.xml i wan't to replace the literal username and password with the values i already setup in environment variables. Is it possible to do this somehow?

i don't use Spring, just Java and hibernate.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.zegasoftware.jpa"
                      transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.zegasoftware.entities.Movie</class>
        <class>com.zegasoftware.entities.People</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="none"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.provider"
                      value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<db_name>"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                      value="<pass>"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zegasoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-movies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <postgres.version>42.5.4</postgres.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Thank you.

Maven,
Java 18,
Hibernate JPA 2,
PostgresQL 15

I've searched online and i cannot find a right answer !